# Не работают hint и balloon в react-yandex-maps. В чем может быть дело?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Всем добрый день. Изучаю react-yandex-maps. Пытаюсь вывести хинт или балун следующим образом:

```
const mapState = { center: [56.85, 53.2], zoom: 12 };
const placeMark = {
    geometry: [56.848217, 53.236675],
    properties: {
        hintContent: 'Это хинт',
        balloonContent: 'Это балун'
    }
}

class MapContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <YMaps>
                <Map state={mapState}>
                    <Placemark {...placeMark} />
                </Map>
            </YMaps>
        );
    }
}
```

Навожу указателем или кликаю на плэйсмарке на картах и ничего не происходит. Пожалуйста подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вообщем отвечаю на собственный же вопрос. Для того, чтобы появились всплывающие подсказки, необходимо подключить два модуля: `modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint']}`. И тогда рабочий пример будет примерно такой:

```
const mapState = { center: [56.85, 53.2], zoom: 12 };
    const placeMark = {
    geometry: [56.848217, 53.236675],
    properties: {
        hintContent: 'Это хинт',
        balloonContent: 'Это балун'
    }
    modules: {
        ['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint']
    }
}

class MapContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <YMaps>
                <Map state={mapState}>
                    <Placemark {...placeMark} />
                </Map>
            </YMaps>
        );
    }
}
```

Может кому-то пригодится)

Более подробнее написано [здесь](https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps/blob/4ed36fe4a8b131826608901bd5db0054e12f8458/docs/pages/migration-guide.mdx#L84).

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Прям выручил modules: { ['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint'] }

Comment: Причем интересно: если однажды добавил modules в каком-либо геообъекте, то в остальных добавлять не обязательно

Answer (score 2):

Вот тебе пример реализации)

```js
ymaps.ready(initq);

function initq()
{var myMapw=new ymaps.Map('map',{center:[56.85, 53.2],zoom:12});
   var myPlacemarkw=new ymaps.Placemark([56.848217, 53.236675],
{
hintContent: 'Stack Overflow',
balloonContent:'Stack Overflow на русском'
},
{
iconLayout:'default#image',
iconImageHref:'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-yablogs/51778/file_1511958710909/orig',
iconImageSize:[100,36],
iconImageOffset:[-50,-18]
});
myMapw.geoObjects.add(myPlacemarkw)};
```

```css
div#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU'></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

другой пример на react-yandex-maps

```
import React from 'react';
import { YMaps, Map, Placemark } from 'react-yandex-maps';

import myIcon from 'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-yablogs/51778/file_1511958710909/orig';

const mapState = { center: [56.848217, 53.236675], zoom: 12 };

const IconCustomImage = () =>
  <YMaps>
    <Map state={mapState}>
      <Placemark
        geometry={{
          coordinates: mapState.center,
        }}
        properties={{
          hintContent: 'Stack Overflow',
          balloonContent: 'Stack Overflow на русском',
        }}
        options={{
          iconLayout: 'default#image',
          iconImageHref: myIcon,
          iconImageSize: [100, 36],
          iconImageOffset: [-50, -18],
        }}
      />
    </Map>
  </YMaps>;

export default IconCustomImage;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вопрос был как использовать `yandex-maps` в связке с `react`.

Comment: Дело в том, что как показано выше иконка отображается но, ни всплывающего хинта, ни балуна не появляется (

Comment: добавил для react-yandex-maps

Comment: Вы сами то этот код запускали? Появились у вас всплывающие элементы?

Comment: https://gribnoysup.github.io/react-yandex-maps/#/sandbox/geoobjects/icon-custom-image

Comment: Это я тоже видел... Именно этот пример и завел в тупик.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Placemark
  geometry={[55.684758, 37.738521]}
  modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint']}
/>;
```

[Отсюда](https://github.com/gribnoysup/react-yandex-maps/blob/4ed36fe4a8b131826608901bd5db0054e12f8458/docs/pages/migration-guide.mdx#L84)